# Docker compose and sitespeedio - running a prescript results in a typeerror: cannot read property of undefined

Tags: performance-testing

Steps to reproduce:

- Run docker compose:

'docker-conpose run sitespeed.io -c cable --preScript login.js https://aa/b/c'

running on chrome (latest) results in the following error:

**TypeError: Cannot read property 'request' of undefined.**

I am running sitespeed.io: 4.3.9 | browsertime: 1.0.0-beta.23 coach: 0.30.4

Note: I can use "docker run" command with a prescript but not with "docker-compose run"

stacktrace:

```
[2017-01-27 17:00:35] TypeError: Cannot read property 'request' of undefined
at Object.harFromEvents   (/usr/src/app/node_modules/browsertime/lib/support/chromePerflogParser.js:471:18)
at runner.getLogs.timeout.map.tap.then
```